# good practice for logging in users on app startup

Tags: session, mobile, authentication

I have noticed that apps like Facebook and Twitter don't require you to login each time you open up your app (mobile), even if you have just changed your password.

In general, what's a good practice to log in the user when they open the app? I was thinking of storing account & password somewhere and have them sent to the server to process login each time the app is opened. However, it seems like Facebook and Twitter keep their user sessions alive for as long as possible, in this case, how would one log in the user, and what is in the request to be sent?

Comment: Look into token authentication. Both Twitter and Facebook use an implementation called OAuth.  When you formally login, you are given an auth token (just a relatively small encrypted string) which you then present to the server each time you want to do something with requires authentication.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen so do I store this token locally at the client side? Also, having to keep all these sessions alive even they're not in use, wouldn't it use up the server's memory quickly?

Comment: Yes, you store the token locally on the client side (e.g. in shared preferences on Android), but the token is _not_ stored in the HTTP session.  This is the really nice thing about them.  Also it is trivial to store such a small string on your users' phone.